# Using AWS glue schema registry with custom SerDe clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, confluent-schema-registry

For supporting schema registry on my MSK topic, I found two options -

AWS Glue Schema Registry; and
Confluent Schema Registry
Since, Glue SR is fully managed by AWS, I would prefer to use that. However, my producer and consumer clients are written in Java

I cannot find such url for the glue registry I created. Their java client does take in properties like region name, registry name and other properties (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-dg.pdf#schema-registry). Is there any way this url can be found out, or should I switch to confluent SR, which is not a managed service?

Comment: The [AWS Glue Schema Registry Installing SerDe Libraries documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-gs.html#schema-registry-gs-serde) shows the required properties.

Comment: @Chin I think the question is asking for how to use the registry, for example, externally from AWS where you'd need to point to a specific registry address

Comment: _should I switch to confluent SR, which is not a managed service_ - But it can be https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/cp-component/schema-reg-cloud-config.html